# Windows App Certification Kit hangs

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I have developed windows 10 App and uploaded that to windows store. However, I wanted to apply Windows Certification App Kit. The testing hangs during these two stages;

Direct3D trim after suspend
     In progress...
UTF-8 file encoding
     In progress...

I don't use any of those features in my app, but I don't understand why it should hang during process?

Thank you!

Comment: Same for me. I couldn't even cancel the test :-(

Comment: I found solution for it. While running the test, simply un-check those tests which you haven't used in your desktop.

Comment: Yes, I simply disable the 3D test as a workaround but sometimes I forget... :-( It would be better to have a solution instead... but at least it's working.

Comment: Same for me. 
"UTF-8 file encoding and"
"Direct3D trim after suspend" hang and it is not possible to cancel the test. The only solution is to restart Visual Studio which is really annoying

Comment: @ARH, did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same issue:

*"Direct3D trim after suspend In progress... UTF-8 file encoding In progress..."*

Problem was that **I didn't try to run the Release Version** locally **first**. It didn't run because I used preprocessor directives like so:

```
public static LicenseInformation licenseInformation = null;
```

...

```
#if DEBUG
        ...
        ...
        licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
#else
        licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
#endif
```

"CurrentApp" did cause an exception.. I use code like this now:

```
#if DEBUG
        ...
        ...
        licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
#else
        try
        {
            licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        } 
#endif
```

And when working with the licenseInformation somewhere I check if it is not null before I use it...

I also found some other issues (warnings) in my code by using "Run Code Analysis on Solution"..

So **in my case it was a problem with my code**.

Answer (score 0):

WACK "Hangs" because it is waiting for the app to start.The problem occurs if you use packages that internally use native code. An example is SQLite (Written in C++).

SQLite for Universal Windows Platform requires this Directive to be included in Properties/Default.rd.xml. Otherwise the external code will throw exceptions when your app is run in native mode (Release build in Visual Studio).

```
<Type Name="System.Collections.ArrayList" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

For details about this directive and EntityFramework.Sqlite (EF7), see: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html